# Append is overwriting existing dictionary in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python, and I have a python program that is supposed to take inputs and store them into a dictionary and store that dictionary into a list, but for some reason, it's overwriting the stored dictionary in the list with the new one at each loop.

```
total_properties_sold = 0
total_commission = 0
bonus_pay = 0
employees = [] #empty list to store dictonary of employees information
employee = {} #empty dictonary to store the information of employees

while True:
    number_of_employees = input("Enter number of employees who have worked this week: ")
    if number_of_employees.isdigit(): #validation check to ensure input is a digit
        number_of_employees = int(number_of_employees) #if input is digit, convert to int
        if number_of_employees >= 2 and number_of_employees <= 5: #validates the range of input
            break
        else:
            print("Input invalid... enter a digit\n")
            
    else:
        print("Input invalid... enter a digit\n")
        

#for loop to enter the details of the number of employees
for number in range(number_of_employees):
    name = input("Enter employee name: ")

    while True: #validation check to ensure input is a digit
        id = input("Enter employee id: ")
        if id.isdigit():
            id = int(id)
            break
        else:    
            print("Invalid data type... enter a number\n")

    while True:
        properties_sold = input("enter number of properties sold by employee: ")
        if properties_sold.isdigit():
            properties_sold = int(properties_sold)
            break
        else: 
            print("Invalid data type... enter a number")

    total_properties_sold += properties_sold #calculates the total properties sold this week
    employee_commission = properties_sold * 500 
    employee_commission = float(employee_commission) #converts commission into a float
    total_commission += employee_commission #calculates the total commission this week
    total_commission = float(total_commission) #converts total commission into float

    #add employee information into the employee dictonary
    employee["name"] = name
    employee["employee id"] = id
    employee["properties sold"] = properties_sold
    employee["commission"] = employee_commission

    employees.append(employee) #adding the employee dictonary into employees list
    
    print(employees)
```

The expected output should be

```
[{'name': 'employee1', 'employee id': 1, 'properties sold': 4, 'commission': 2000.0}, {'name': 'employee2', 'employee id': 2, 'properties sold': 3, 'commission': 1500.0}, {'name': 'employee3', 'employee id': 3, 'properties sold': 10, 'commission': 5000.0}]
```

But I get:

```
[{'name': 'employee3', 'employee id': 3, 'properties sold': 10, 'commission': 5000.0}, {'name': 'employee3', 'employee id': 3, 'properties sold': 10, 'commission': 5000.0}, {'name': 'employee3', 'employee id': 3, 'properties sold': 10, 'commission': 5000.0}]
 

```

Comment: You are appending *the same* dictionary (`employee`) multiple times, changing its contents between appends, which is why you end up with what looks like multiple copies of the *last* employee.

Comment: You can avoid appending the same instance of the dict, by appending a copy `employees.append(employee.copy())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you assign `employee = {}` at the beginning of the code, and it is never reassigned after that, so the code is always referring to *the same object*.

When you set `employee["name"] = name` for the next employee, you're still referring to the same `employee` object, and it affects the instance of `employee` that is *already in the list*.

To fix this, assign `employee` to a fresh dictionary at the top of the for loop:

```
for number in range(number_of_employees):
    employee = {}
    name = input("Enter employee name: ")
```

This reassigns the variable name `employee` to a fresh value, and breaks the connection to the previous values.

Comment: I appreciate that, the code now works. if it isnt too much of a hassle could you explain to me why my first attempt didnt work. my understanding of it was during each loop the inputs for the dictionary would just overwrite the existing/previous inputs stored in the dictionary, so the newly update dictionary could be appended onto the end of the employees list.  Im a CS student and still a novice at programming, would appreciate the help.

Comment: @Rohail `employees.append(employee)` It seems like you expect this to append a _copy_ of employee to the list; but that is not what happens.  _the actual object_ is appended to the list (and since this is in a loop, the object itself is appended to the list many times.)  So the next time you assign `employee["name"] = name`, it affects all of the items in the list because they're all _identical references to the same object_.

Comment: @Rohail Other languages may not behave this way, but Python does.